# Python socket server - continue to receive client data

Tags: python, sockets

How can I have a Python socket server tell me when there is a connection and then CONTINUE to give me back data that the client sends? When I do it, it connects and then just loops over, telling me it connected over and over again.

I,just want it to connect and then continually check (or grab) data sent to the server.

Also, how can I tell if the client disconnected?

```
address = ('', 7777)
server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
try:
    server_socket.bind(address)
except Exception, e:
    print colored("Address already in use", 'red')

server_socket.listen(2)

print colored("Socket ready", 'blue')
while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    hostIP = addr[0]
    port = addr[1]

    try:
        host = gethostbyaddr(hostIP)[0]
    except:
        host = hostIP
    print colored("Got connection from: " + host, 'blue')
    try:
        recv_data = server_socket.recv(2048)
        print("Got: " + recv_data)
    except:
        print "nothing"
        recv_data = "" # this is because I test what it is later, but that's irrevlevant.
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to show what you've tried.

Comment: Typically speaking, a socket server binds to a socket, listens for connections, accepts/rejects connections, send/receive data on accepted connections. You appear to be doing NOTHING with the connection. You need to handle the connection.

Comment: Ok, so it receives the data. That help? It MIGHT also need to have multiple connections. But only maybe.

Comment: Not really. Still need the code you've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't do anything with `client_socket`; ie: the actual client connection. Furthermore, the server
cannot know how much the client wants to send and so it must **CONTINUE** (ie: in a
loop) to receive data. When the connection sends 'empty' data, the connection
is terminated and the server goes back to listening. If you want the server to
accept new connections and continue to receive data from existing connections
look up the `threading` module.

```
import socket

address = ('', 7777)
server_socket = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
try:
    server_socket.bind(address)
except Exception, e:
    print colored("Address already in use", 'red')

server_socket.listen(2)

print colored("Socket ready", 'blue')
while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    hostIP = addr[0]
    port = addr[1]

    try:
        host = gethostbyaddr(hostIP)[0]
    except:
        host = hostIP
    print colored("Got connection from: " + host, 'blue')
    while True:
        try:
            recv_data = client_socket.recv(2048)
            if not recv_data:
                break
            print("Got: " + recv_data)
        except socket.error, e:
            print "nothing"
            recv_data = "" # this is because I test what it is later, but that's irrevlevant.
```

Comment: Ok, I'll defo look into that module for socketing. I already use it, but hadn't thought of it for sockets. Thanks